# MPMoviePlayerController shows blank screen or crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6.1

I have a UIViewController subclass called videoPlayerViewController.
In storyboard I dragged out a UIViewController. I set the class correctly in Storyboard.
I put a button on the screen. When I click the button, it executes the method playVideo:.

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{
 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

 MPMoviePlayerController *player =
 [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
 [player prepareToPlay];
 [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
 [self.view addSubview: player.view];
 [player play];
}
```

I get a black screen that does nothing.

This is the simplest version of the code I've had in this method over the last 6 hours.

I've tried every StackOverflow answer out there.
I just want to play a video that I stream from the internet.

If I set:

```
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

the screen reads "loading" for  a second, and then crashes.
What exactly am I doing wrong?

I understand there are so many MPMoviePlayerController questions out there, and to just ask a general "How does it work" question seems ludicrous. I've been at this almost 6 hours now and no Google/Stack Overflow/Apple Documentation search has made this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your provided code but created a MoviePlayerController property named mcp in the header file that I assigned to player to after creating it. That worked for me. The movie loaded and played just fine.

In the .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mcp;
```

In the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

    _mcp = player;

    [self.view addSubview: _mcp.view];
    [_mcp play];
}
```

Comment: Well the answer goes to you sir.
I created a new project and used your code and it works.
I've been trying it in my current project and it didn't work there and still doesn't. No idea what the problem is, but at least I can look elsewhere

Comment: Glad I could help. I recalled there is an issue where ARC isn't properly retaining an MPMoviePlayerController object so you need to assign it to a property as a workaround. That worked in one of my projects.

Comment: Dec 2013 .. TIP - it is hugely flakey about file name extensions (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard.  Bizarre.  Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes.  Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken.

Comment: I have used MPMoviePlayerViewController and presented it but I am getting black screen while video loading